# Multiple NSFetchedResultsControllers in same tableview - sort with based on same property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

It seems to me that implementing two `NSFetchedResultsControllers` in the same `UITableView` is not a problem, as long as the results are sectioned.

I have two different type of entities who both have the property "first_name". I would like to sort the `UITableView` using this property from both my entities, and section them based on the first character of "first_name"(I have that character as a property as well).

Example. I have two entities (`supervisor`, `employee`). I want to present them both in the same `UITableView` sorted by the "first_name" property.

Is that something that is possible to achieve, and how in that case?

Comment: Sure, this can be done by creating a data source that aggregates and re-sorts the data encapsulated by the two fetched results controllers. It's not a trivial amount of work to get the aggregate sorting right. I would suggest instead having an entity that is the super entity for both of your current entities, with a first_name property, and instead using a single results controller that fetches that entity (and it's sub entities). Much simpler all around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How i solve it at the moment is that i don't use an nsfetchedresultscontroller. I just fetch the objects from core data directly and sort them in my viewcontroller. Im afraid that the objects might get faulted if i end up with to many objects. is it possible to continue with my current solution without having to worry about the faulting possibility?

Comment: You should always plan for faults. Faults happen on the property level.